# Cross browser login prevention

Tags: java, xml, spring, model-view-controller

I have developed my website using spring mvc. But the problem is, after login when I copy the url from one browser (suppose chrome) to another browser(IE), it is redirecting me to the custom error page in logged in status(in IE), but it should give me login page only. Do I need to make any changes in XML file?
I have attached the XML file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  version="3.1">
  <display-name>Intelligent Data Works</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>*.woff2</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>*.woff</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>*.mp4</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.PNG</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ModuleList</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.comsnet.idw.diw.util.ModuleList</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>  -->

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 <error-page> 
     <location>/WEB-INF/views/error.jsp</location>
   </error-page> 
   
     <context-param>
     <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j_idw.properties</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   
   <filter>
  <filter-name>AccessFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.comsnet.idw.common.AccessFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>AccessFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/home/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/RDW/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/DIW/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/IMW/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/DSW/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/TSW/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/DOW/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/DIQ/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
 
  <security-constraint>   
 <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name><strong>restricted methods</strong></web-resource-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>PUT</http-method>
      <http-method>MKCOL</http-method>
      <http-method>DEBUG</http-method>
      <http-method>PROPFIND</http-method>
      <http-method>PROPPATCH</http-method>
      <http-method>MOVE</http-method>
      <http-method>COPY</http-method>
      <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
      <http-method>GETLIB</http-method>
      <http-method>LOCK</http-method>
      <http-method>UNLOCK </http-method>
      <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
     </web-resource-collection>
     <auth-constraint /> 
   </security-constraint>  
     
<!-- <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener> -->

<!-- <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>
      
    <filter>  
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>  
    </filter>  
    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
    </filter-mapping>  -->
    <session-config> <session-timeout>30</session-timeout> </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Please, consider of updating your code with the error code.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Cookie. While logging in, create a cookie and save in the browser. As cookie is browser specific, it will not be saved in other browsers. Now, in the page where we can check if the session exists or not, we can check if the cookie with correct value exists or not! Thus preventing cross browser login.